# update object in array that contains specific values using dynamic field name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Currently, I have a Mongo Collection that contains objects like this one:

```json
{
    "_id" : "5a1d3298dece873bfd6cf593",
    "rights" : [
        ...
        {
            "module" : "messenger",
            "right" : "writeToResident",
            "default" : true
        }, 
        {
            "module" : "messenger",
            "right" : "writeToUnionCouncil",
            "default" : true
        },
        {
            "module" : "news",
            "right" : "see",
            "default" : true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I just want to do something simple: edit the `default` value in the object in the `rights` array that contains values "messenger" for `module` and "writeToResident" for `right`.

I tried many things like

```js
const setter = {};
setter[`rights.$.${module}.${right}`] = value;
DefaultRoles.update(defaultRoleId, {
 $set: setter
});

// OR

const setter = {};
setter[`rights.${module}.${right}`] = value;
DefaultRoles.update(defaultRoleId, {
 $set: setter
});
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to do this ?

**EDIT**

With your help I tried this:

```js
DefaultRoles.update({
  "_id": defaultRoleId,
  "rights.module": module,
  "rights.right": right
}, {
  $set: {
    'rights.$.default': value,
  }
});
```

But something very strange happened: sometime the edited object is not the right one.
For exemple, when I update `module: "manual"` `right: "write"`, `module: "actuality"` `right: "write"` is updated instead.

Comment: To point you in the right direction, your query would be `DefaultRoles.update({ '_id': defaultRoleId, 'rights.module': 'messenger', 'rights.right': 'writeToResident' }, { '$set': { 'rights.$.default': value } });`

Comment: I followed your instructions but there are some bugs with it... @chridam